# Cannot get user id - 404 User not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

When I navigate to the user/dashboard, I should see the user id at the end of the url but instead I see `http://localhost:3000/profile/$%7B_id%7D` no matter who is signed in and I get a 404 error with the response: `error: "User not found"`. I don't know where `$%7B_id%7D` is coming from.

What do I need to change in my code to fix this and get the correct user id?

```
export const isAuthenticated = () => {
    if (typeof window == 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt'));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

apiUser.js

```
import { API } from "../config";

export const read = (userId, token) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/user/${userId}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

export const update = (userId, token, user) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/user/${userId}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

export const updateUser = (user, next) => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.getItem("jwt")) {
            let auth = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jwt"));
            auth.user = user;
            localStorage.setItem("jwt", JSON.stringify(auth));
            next();
        }
    }
};
```

UserDashboard.js

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const {
    user: { _id, name, email, role }
  } = isAuthenticated();

  const userLinks = () => {
    return (
            <Link className="nav-link" to="/profile/${_id}">
              Update Profile
            </Link>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Are you sure your isAuthenticated() returns the proper _id? Please show your isAuthenticated() code as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated the question with my code. @VipulPatil

Comment: I still see no `isAuthenticated` code @Rahni

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong code. I've updated it @RedBaron

Comment: @Rahni check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to use template strings and `{}` when using `_id` here: `to="/profile/${_id}">`

Changed to:  `` to={`/profile/${_id}`}> `` and `_id` is working.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that this function:

```
export const isAuthenticated = () => {
    if (typeof window == 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt'));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

returns a boolean

but here:

```
  const {
    user: { _id, name, email, role }
  } = isAuthenticated();
```

you are trying to abstract `_id` out of it and it doesn't know what `_id` is. so you need to make sure that it returns an object with these keys if you're going to destructure

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RedBaron but I've just realised I made a silly mistake. I was getting an error because I didn't use {} and template strings when using _id here: `to="/profile/${_id}">`.

Comment: Yeah it's all fixed. Thanks. @RedBaron

Comment: no worries. feel free to upvote the answer and add your own answer so people know the question is done :)